# File exists in path but can't delete in android 10 only

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I tried to delete a file using a file path and it works on all android versions except android 10. I don't know what's the matter.

```
File fdlt = new File(getFilePath(bitmapUri));
            Log.e("TAGO", getFilePath(bitmapUri));
            if (fdlt.exists()) {
                if (fdlt.delete()) {
                    Log.e("TAGO", "File Deleted");
                } else {
                    Log.e("TAGO", "File Not Deleted");
                }
            }
```

By using `fdlt.exists()` it is proved that the file exists but it doesn't delete while in other android versions it deletes it instantly without any issues. P.S: I am using fragment.

I am searching about it for a week so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, can i see the full path of your file?

Comment: Can you please provide what is the stacktrace error that's being displayed in your Log?

Comment: @ThànhHàVăn Hey. This is the full path: _/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/some title.jpg_ ... When I go to the photos app and check the info of the picture then it's the exactly same path that I am getting in my log.

Comment: @LuisAguilar There is no particular stacktrace error in my logcat. Just some random stuff going on as usual, nothing important. Do you want me to send you whole logcat or something for more clarification?